# Are users reluctant to upvote posts with score 9?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, up-votes

The "nice question" and "nice answer" badges are awarded when questions and answers reach a score of 10 or more.

I am relatively new to the stackexchange world and I noticed a strange behavior: some questions do not get upvoted for a long time if their score is equal to 9, sometimes they never reach a score of 10. This holds especially for user with medium-low reputation: I myself have [three questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414/melfnt?tab=questions) with score 9 on Puzzling Stack Exchange and less than three questions with any different score (excluding duplicate and closed questions with score -1/0/1).

> Are people reluctant to upvote a post with score 9 knowing that this action would make the author award a new badge?

I hope the answer is NO, after all we have very little benefits if the other users have less badges. How can we check if this is really happening? Are there any statistics on the score "frequencies"?

Of course I'm not complaining about the score of my posts: I know that to get more upvotes I should write better questions and answers. I'm just curious about this behavior. Also, I know that most upvotes are given in the first few days, so if the score of a question/answer has been 9 for a long time it probably won't change anymore.

Comment: Any resilient data regarding your observations?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no sorry I would like to see some statistics but I don't know how to do it

Comment: You can do that using [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/introducing-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-aka-sede).

Comment: If you are suggesting that such behaviour is to prevent the earning of the [Nice-Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) and [Nice-Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) badges (10 votes), then one would see a similar pattern at 24 votes for the [Good-Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) badge too; and to a lesser extent for the other more difficult votes based badges. Also voting patterns are different on different sites, as you'll note here, so you'll need statistical info from over a dozen at least.

Comment: @Rob this was my supposition but apparently it is wrong

Comment: Melfnt, the current answer's query may work on one site but when tried on other sites, [such as SO or Physics](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1216199#graph) it produces jumbled (unsorted) results; making a site vs. site comparison difficult. Arguably zero or one upvote are the most *popular* vote total, depriving you of everything.

Comment: Why would I want to prevent someone else from getting a badge? I don't consider the current score in voting - I just consider whether I thought the content was helpful or not.

Comment: @Rob looks like the query is missing an `ORDER BY score` line at the very bottom.

Comment: @scohe001 That's [correct](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1216410/distribution-of-scores-2-0-for-https-meta-stackexchange-com-a-345745-282094#graph), and the extended version shows no little bump at 24 on Stack Overflow - Myth Busted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, that's not the case.

Since you refer to Puzzling, I made [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/1216199#graph) to view the distribution of scores on that specific site.

There's no evident spike at a score of 9. This would indicate that a score of 9 does not have a special effect on voting.

[image]